# Is this sentence positive or neutral?

Tags: meaning

It is written in an e-mail that **You receive this e-mail as you have been assigned to a project.** 
I could not understand its actual meaning. Does it say you are assigned to a project or if you are assigned to a project...
Thanks!

Comment: Side note: the verb phrase "You receive" is not correct. It should be **you have received**.  And **a projects** is not grammatical.  **a** designates a singular, not a plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is neutral. It means you "you receive this e-mail **because** you have been assigned to a project". The word 'as' in a sentence like that functions like "since" or "because".